# Visual Studio 2015 "Run All" Link Defaulting to Another Culture

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest

I have a .Net 3.5 ASP.Net project with a separate unit test .Net 4.0 project that I use Visual Studio 2015 to edit.

When I run the unit tests separately by method or class, the tests pass as expected.

Some of the tests fail when I click the “Run All” link in the Test Explorer or commit the source changes to activate an on premise Team Foundation Server 2015 build script.

I have identified the problem to the thread culture defaulting to Germany in the “Run All” link and build server instances versus passing tests running as English (United States).

I am editing this code and running it in production in Ohio without any requirements for any other culture settings. How do I default the MSTest to English (United States) and why does MSTest run in a German culture?